# search and append new line in c#

Tags: c#, search, append, file-writing

I have code like  this:

```
reset <= '1';
ds <= '0';
wait for 20ns;
wait until clk = '0';
reset <= '0';
wait until clk = '1';
wait until clk = '0';
inexp <= x"00903ad9";
inmod <= x"03b2c159";
report "clock init";
indata <= x"72624326";
wait until clk = '1';
wait for 2ns;
ds <= '1';
wait until ready = '0';
ds <= '0';
wait until ready = '1';
wait for 500ns;
reset <= '1';
ds <= '0';
wait for 20ns;
wait until clk = '0';
reset <= '0';
```

and I want to search `"<="` in each line and add a append new line before this line.(write to file)
I find this word in my code but for append have not idea!
get find and give line by this code:

```
    int counter = 1;
    string line;

    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("e:\\file.txt");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("<="))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString() + ": " + line);                    
        }
        counter++;
    }

    file.Close();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write to file new text change your code to:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("e:\\file.txt");
System.IO.StreamWriter resultFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("e:\\resultFile.txt", false);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("<="))
    {
        resultFile.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + counter.ToString() + ": " + line);                    
    }

    // if you don't want to write lines without "<=" - delete "else" block
    else
    {
        resultFile.WriteLine(counter.ToString() + ": " + line);    
    }
    counter++;
}
```

In this code you create new file and write every line from `file.txt` to it. If line contains `<=` you append new line at the beginning.

So, in disk `E` you will find new file `resultFile.txt` with needed text.